# java persistence works with reading from database, silently fails to insert / update

Tags: java, insert, persistence, persist

I have created a simple java web (Vaadin) application project using JPA and it works for reading entities from database. When I try to use either persist() or merge(), nothing happens in database.
When looking at the logs, there are SELECT queries, but no INSERT / UPDATE.

I am using Glassfish 3.1 with JDBC resource defined, persistence.xml to use that resource (JTA).
I am using default configuration files, generated automatically by Eclipse.

There is also another similar project done by someone else, uses the same JTA and this problem does not appear. Looked over its configuration and didn't find anything important.

Both projects do not use transactions.

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="MapperPersistence">
    <jta-data-source>mapper</jta-data-source>
         <class>pl.bdk.mapper.domain.jpaImpl.MappingImpl</class>
...
         <class>pl.bdk.mapper.domain.jpaImpl.UserImpl</class>
             <properties>
                 <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE" />
             </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Java code**

```
public class MappingService {
    public static int createMapping(String clientProductId, User user) {
        MappingImpl mapping = new MappingImpl();
        mapping.setUser(user);
        mappingDao.save(mapping);
        return mapping.getMappingId();
    }
}

...
public class MappingDao {
    public void save(MappingImpl mapping) {
        entityManager.persist(mapping);
    }
}

...
@Entity
@Table("t_mapping")
public class MappingImpl() {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="T_MAPPING_MAPPINGID_GENERATOR", sequenceName="S_MAPPING_ID", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="T_MAPPING_MAPPINGID_GENERATOR")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private User user;

... getters and setters...
}
```

Comment: post the code where you think you are inserting

Comment: You're always using transactions. If you haven't specified opening and closing points of a transaction you are using an implicit transaction which is only guaranteed to be persisted when you call close() on the EntityManager, are you doing that?

Comment: When you are using JTA as a resource for transaction, then before any database operation you must open a transaction and then should try to commit or rollback the same depending on if there is any exception. It would be helpful if you can at-least post the persistence.xml.

Comment: @Thor84no: The effect is the same with or without close(). flush() gives an exception (because I don't begin a transaction)

Comment: Ok. I'm not sure what exactly it is then, just be aware that you *have to* close the EntityManager, and that calling persist() or merge() is a hint to the persistence layer, it doesn't guarantee it will be done *now*, but it should be done at some point, no later than the close().

Comment: @M.J.: I'd rather not use transactions for now. Will try this though, just to make sure.

Comment: Generally, I know that persist() doesn't have to result in instant INSERT statement, but in this case it doesn't even after entityManager.close().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the matter seemed simple, but it isn't.

This post helped me a lot: [Hibernate doesn't save and doesn't throw exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799889/hibernate-doesnt-save-and-doesnt-throw-exceptions)

First of all - JPA needs some kind of transaction mechanism. Normally it is managed underneath and needs no setup.
This means the easiest way is to create an EJB (Enterprise Java Bean) project, where EntityManager would be injected with @PersistenceContext. If one prefers to create the EntityManager locally (no EJB), a transaction mechanism still has to be provided. More info in the above post.